# How to force a badge to always be a circle?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a notification badge that sometimes it is a circle but sometimes oval depending on the number that's inside it. Say i have 5 new notification then since its a small number the badge is a nice circle but if the number is 22 or 523 then it is oval. Is there a way to make this badge always a circle? I am using materialize css and my html/css code is the following:

```css
.notification-badge {
  position: relative;
  /*right: -12px;
  top: -84px;*/
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #FF4081;
  // margin: 0 -.8em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 4px 5px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
}

.notification-icon--fixed {
  max-height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<a data-activates="mdi-social-group-add" title="Convites" style="" class="notification-button notification-icon--fixed">
  <div class="block-elem">
    <i class="mdi-social-group-add large">
        <small class="notification-badge">22</small>
      </i>
  </div>
</a>
```

Here is a image of my current result:

[image: Notifications]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with pure CSS.

Here's a simplified example of how you can use flexbox and some padding tricks to guarantee an element's height always matches its width.  I have removed some of your extra HTML to make the example clearer, which should work with minimal tweaking.

```css
.notification-icon--fixed {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #FF4081;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  
  /* Alignment */
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* Adjust as required: */
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Height = width */
.notification-icon--fixed::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a class="notification-icon--fixed">
  <small class="notification-badge">1</small>
</a>

<a class="notification-icon--fixed">
  <small class="notification-badge">12</small>
</a>

<a class="notification-icon--fixed">
  <small class="notification-badge">1500</small>
</a>
```

The essence of this technique is setting `padding-bottom: 100%` on the `::after` pseudo-element, and `display: inline-flex` for alignment.

Comment: Haven't tested it but at first glance it looks like with this solution badges of different widths will have different heights. Whether this is better UI over having them equally sized with extra content overflowing is debatable.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I totally agree, I would rather have consistent height as well.  I just wanted to show that this idea is possible without needing JS.

Comment: If equally sized badges are preferred, it can be easily adapted by setting the desired `width` and centering content. It's advantage is it avoids any concern about `box-sizing`, unequal `padding` values, etc... Well done!

Comment: It worked ! Thank you :) But didn't quite understand your explanation of the technique, could you explain why is setting padding on the `::after` doing the trick ?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu That's exactly what i did ! By setting the width i could get all badges to work properly.

Comment: @TiagoConceiçao It's effectively the same technique covered in way more depth in this [responsive square article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/14/css-responsive-square/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need to set a fixed `width` on `.notification-badge`, equal to its `height`.

```
.notification-badge {
  width: 13px;
}
```

The easiest way to get the correct value is to inspect the element and get its height in `px`. Note that if `box-sizing` is set to `border-box`, `padding` and `border` values are included in `width` and `height`. This is important since you have different values set to vertical and horizontal `padding`. So, most likely, you'll need to set the `width` with `2px` lower than the `height`. In order to center the text inside the now fixed width element, you might want to use flexbox:

```
.notification-badge {
  width: 13px; /* set based on making it equal with height */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

See it working:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
.notification-badge {
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #FF4081;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 12px;
}

.notification-icon--fixed {
  max-height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
.notification-badge {
  width: 14px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

```html
<a data-activates="mdi-social-group-add" title="Convites" style="" class="notification-button notification-icon--fixed">
  <div class="block-elem">
    <i class="mdi-social-group-add large">
        <small class="notification-badge">22</small>
      </i>
  </div>
</a>
<a data-activates="mdi-social-group-add" title="Convites" style="" class="notification-button notification-icon--fixed">
  <div class="block-elem">
    <i class="mdi-social-group-add large">
        <small class="notification-badge">1232</small>
      </i>
  </div>
</a>
<a data-activates="mdi-social-group-add" title="Convites" style="" class="notification-button notification-icon--fixed">
  <div class="block-elem">
    <i class="mdi-social-group-add large">
        <small class="notification-badge">3855</small>
      </i>
  </div>
</a>
```

You could also use Javascript to set the width of the element:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
  $('.notification-badge').each(function() {
    $(this).css({width: ($(this).height() - 2) + 'px'})
  })
})
```

Note I'm deducting the `2px` padding difference.

Comment: raw CSS is always better!

Comment: When i use your css-only solution the numbers inside the badge jumps outside of it and there's no way i could put them back.

Comment: Without the possibility to inspect it (a [mcve]), I can't help with that.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using JQuery, here is a solution for your problem.

```js
if ($(".notification-badge").html().length == 3) {
  console.log("for 3 decimal");
  $('.notification-badge').css("padding", "8px 5px")
}
```

```css
.notification-badge {
  position: relative;
  /*  right: -12px;
 top: -84px; */
  color: #66f;
  background-color: #FF4081;
  margin: 0 0.8em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 4px 5px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  /*   font-size:40px; */
}

.notification-icon--fixed {
  max-height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-activates="mdi-social-group-add" title="Convites" style="" class="notification-button notification-icon--fixed">
  <div class="block-elem">
    <i class="mdi-social-group-add large">
    <small class="notification-badge">248</small>
  </i>
  </div>
```